# Can I change the image position dropdown in Redactor?

Tags: redactor, image

I want to change the image position dropdown in the "Edit Image" window or add a new one that give me a different way to control image position. Rather than having this dropdown change the float, I want it to add a class to the image. i.e., instead of "float: left" class="left". How do I do that?